# memory leak python asyncio.create_task

Tags: python, memory-leaks, python-asyncio

can you please explain. Is there any problem with this code?
I've run into a memory leak in my application and my code is written like this. I am creating tasks and then call them one by one, but due to condition constructs they might not get called. Could this be the cause of the memory leak?

```py
import asyncio


async def func(n):
    await asyncio.sleep(n)
    return n


async def main():
    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(func(1))
    task_2 = asyncio.create_task(func(2))

    res_1 = await task_1
    if res_1 == 1:
        return
    res_2 = await task_2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: you should probably cancel `task_2` when you exit early due to `task_1` result https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel

Comment: @Anentropic Are they not automatically canceled when the function exits?